# PHP/http request to ios push notification

Tags: php, ios

I don't want to make myself an app for the sole purpose of pushing a notification to my employer occasionally.

Is there any service where you can request a notification get sent to an iPhone if they have a certain app installed?

There's no windows or mac 'notification' system so I am looking for some way to notify him when a change is made to the website via php or http.

Comment: There are tons of them, have you looked into this at all

Comment: I don't know where to start

Comment: Google for it, some off the top of my head: Prowl, Pushover, Boxcar.